# Flask Ckeditor receives the returned value and is rendered by ‘Render_template’

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ckeditor

I am learning CKEditor in python flask.
It’s no problem to submit documents with this.

[image: Displays normally on the web page]

The content contains the code that needs to be rendered by flask render_template, such as {{ *** }}, but if I need to edit again, pass {{ ckeditor.create (value=content) }} After receiving the text marked with {{ *** }}, it will be rendered by render_template. I don’t want to be rendered by render_template.

I want the returned data to be displayed in the edit box of CKEditor：

[image: This is the content displayed when editing for the first time]

not：

[image: This is the content displayed on the CKEditor of the returned value]

I tried ：

```
<form method="POST">
{{ ckeditor.create(value=content|safe) }}
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</from>
```

but it doesn't seem to work!

I want to know how to solve this problem, or what caused it?

If you can't see the picture, you can [click here](http://139.9.196.227/files/2021-12-30%2018-15-33+stackoverflow%20q%20flask%20ckeditor.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Although no one can answer my question, I found the answer in another version of the official document, so I still share it !
The key to solving the problem is to do some data processing before flask renders the template!

```
return render_template('xxxx.html', content = content.replace( '&', '&amp;'))
```